# Matching $$ using Regex in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

Using a Regex tester:
`(?<UserDataPathXP>\\\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]\$\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\\(?>userDataXP>[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\$\$))` matches `\\server\e$\users\user1$$`

Using PowerShell I have to add a backtick before the second `$` in the users filepath for it to match:

`` "\\server\e$\users\user1$`$" -match "(?<UserDataPathXP>\\\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]\$\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\\(?<userDataXP>[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\$\$))"
True ``

Otherwise it fails:

`"\\server\e$\users\user1$$" -match "(?<UserDataPathXP>\\\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]\$\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\\(?<userDataXP>[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\$\$))"
False`

The input file of the following script contains file paths with usernames all containing a `$$`.  I want the regex to be able to capture the `user$$`, create a directory still with a `$$`, and copy files to it.  How can I get around this problem in the following script?

```
$paths = get-content "E:\paths.txt" 
$ArchiveLocation = "\\Server1\Archive" 
$LogsData = Test-Path "$ArchiveLocation\Archived_UserData\Logs"
$LogsProfiles = Test-Path "$ArchiveLocation\Archived_UserProfiles\Logs"

$regxUsrProfPthXP = "(?<UserProfilePathXP>^((?![a-zA-Z 0-9]*\$\$).)*\\\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]\$\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\\(?<userProfileXP>[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\$))"
$regxUsrDataPthXP = "(?<UserDataPathXP>\\\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]\$\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\\(?<userDataXP>[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\$\$))"
if (-not $LogsProfiles) {
    md "$ArchiveLocation\Archived_UserProfiles\Logs"
}

if (-not $LogsData) {
    md "$ArchiveLocation\Archived_UserData\Logs"
}

foreach ($path in $paths) {

    if ($path -match $regxUsrProfPthXP) {
        $path = $matches.UserProfilePathXP
        $user = $matches.userProfileXP
        RoboCopy $path "$ArchiveLocation\Archived_UserProfiles\$user" /MIR /B /COPY:DATSOU /MOVE /LOG+:$ArchiveLocation\Archived_UserProfiles\Logs\$user.log /R:1 /W:1
    }

    if ($path -match $regxUsrDataPthXP) {
        $path = $matches.UserDataPathXP
        $user = $matches.userDataXP
        RoboCopy $path "$ArchiveLocation\Archived_UserData\$user" /MIR /B /COPY:DATSOU /MOVE /LOG+:$ArchiveLocation\Archived_UserData\Logs\$user.log /R:1 /W:1
    }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use **single quotes** where you define your `regex` and the string so you don't need to escape the `$` using backticks.

```
'\\server\e$\users\user1$$' -match '(?<UserDataPathXP>\\\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]\$\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\\(?<userDataXP>[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\$\$))'
```

Output:

```
True
```

---

So all you have to do is to change

```
$regxUsrProfPthXP = "(?<UserProfilePathXP>^((?![a-zA-Z 0-9]*\$\$).)*\\\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]\$\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\\(?<userProfileXP>[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\$))"
$regxUsrDataPthXP = "(?<UserDataPathXP>\\\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]\$\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\\(?<userDataXP>[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\$\$))"
```

to

```
$regxUsrProfPthXP = '(?<UserProfilePathXP>^((?![a-zA-Z 0-9]*\$\$).)*\\\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]\$\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\\(?<userProfileXP>[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\$))'
$regxUsrDataPthXP = '(?<UserDataPathXP>\\\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]\$\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\\(?<userDataXP>[a-zA-Z 0-9]*\$\$))'
```

Comment: I can use single quotes for the `regex` but how can I do that for the strings which are taken by looping an input file that does not include quotes?

Comment: you don't need to do it there. If the `$path` within your foreach loop contains `\\server\e$\users\user1$$` and you defined your regex using single quotes, it will work

Comment: As simple as that!