# RegEx match is not working if it contains $

Tags: powershell

The following match returns false. How can I change the regular expression to correct it?

```
"hello$world" -match '^hello$(wo|ab).*$' 

"hello$abcde" -match '^hello$(wo|ab).*$'
```

Comment: Well, a `$` has special meaning within both PowerShell double-quoted strings and regex strings.  How do you suppose you might tell the parser(s) to treat it literally?  You're halfway there with your second parameter to `-match`.

Comment: You do use the `$` as an anchor at line end yourself, so how do you expect this to work without escaping the literal `$` with a backslash in the RE? And also either use single quotes in the string to not expand a variable or escape the $ in the string with a backtick.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700802/matching-using-regex-in-powershell

Answer (score 3):

```
'hello$world' -match '^hello\$(wo|ab).*$'
'hello$abcde' -match '^hello\$(wo|ab).*$'
```

You need to quote the left hand side with single quotes so `$world` isn't treated like variable interpolation. You need to escape the `$` in the right hand side so it isn't treated as end of line.

From [About Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules):

> When you enclose a string in double quotation marks (a double-quoted string), variable names that are preceded by a dollar sign (`$`) are replaced with the variable's value before the string is passed to the command for processing.
>
> ...
>
> When you enclose a string in single-quotation marks (a single-quoted string), the string is passed to the command exactly as you type it. No substitution is performed.

From [About Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions):

> The two commonly used anchors are `^` and `$`. The carat `^` matches the start of a string, and `$`, which matches the end of a string. This allows you to match your text at a specific position while also discarding unwanted characters.
>
> ...
>
> #### Escaping characters
>
> The backslash `\` is used to escape characters so they are not parsed by the regular expression engine.
>
> The following characters are reserved: `[]().\^$|?*+{}`.
>
> You will need to escape these characters in your patterns to match them in your input strings.